# Why is this binary tree preorder traversal returning none

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, tree, binary-tree, traversal

Hi I am attempting to solve `leetcode` problem `1379`.

Here is the statement of the problem + link:

https://leetcode.com/problems/find-a-corresponding-node-of-a-binary-tree-in-a-clone-of-that-tree/

[image: Problem]

Here is my failed attempt at a solution:

```
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode:
#     def __init__(self, x):
#         self.val = x
#         self.left = None
#         self.right = None

class Solution:
    def getTargetCopy(self, original: TreeNode, cloned: TreeNode, target: TreeNode) -> TreeNode:
        if cloned:
            if cloned.val == target.val:
                return cloned
            self.getTargetCopy(original, cloned.left, target)
            self.getTargetCopy(original, cloned.right, target)
```

I am failing to understand why this is not working.

I think my solution is doing a preorder traversal of the tree and at each stage asking if the node in the cloned tree exists and if so is it's value equal to the value we are looking for? If it is then return that node and we have found the one we are looking for.

If not then check simply carry on checking the tree. Since the values in the tree are guaranteed to be unique and the target value is guaranteed to be in the tree then and I am visiting every node then surely this must work at finding the answer.

However it is failing the automated tests, it doesn't even pass the example 1 (pictured above) and is saying it is returning `null`.

What am I missing?

EDIT:

I tried printing my original solution with the arguements at each function call:

```
__main__.Solution.getTargetCopy ( self = <__main__.Solution object at 0x000002B15CF31358>, original = 7, cloned = 7, target = 3 )
__main__.Solution.getTargetCopy ( self = <__main__.Solution object at 0x000002B15CF31358>, original = 7, cloned = 4, target = 3 )
__main__.Solution.getTargetCopy ( self = <__main__.Solution object at 0x000002B15CF31358>, original = 7, cloned = None, target = 3 )
__main__.Solution.getTargetCopy ( self = <__main__.Solution object at 0x000002B15CF31358>, original = 7, cloned = None, target = 3 )
__main__.Solution.getTargetCopy ( self = <__main__.Solution object at 0x000002B15CF31358>, original = 7, cloned = 3, target = 3 )
None
```

So as well can see the cloned tree traverses from 7 down to 4 then checks 4's left and right child which are both none, then it checks 7's right child 3 and confirms that it is the same as the target, at this point in the call `cloned.val=3` so the return statement should return the node whose value is 3 which should be the right answer yet it seems to be returning none which is not even the value of cloned at that time (as proven by the print statement showing the arguments) what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the `if` condition is not true, you don't `return` anything.

So change these two lines:

```
self.getTargetCopy(original, cloned.left, target)
self.getTargetCopy(original, cloned.right, target)
```

To:

```
res = self.getTargetCopy(original, cloned.left, target)
if res:
    return res
return self.getTargetCopy(original, cloned.right, target)
```

Or even (using short circuit):

```
return (self.getTargetCopy(original, cloned.left, target)
     or self.getTargetCopy(original, cloned.right, target))
```

Comment: Hi @trincot. Thank you for the answer I will be sure to mark it as accepted soon. I have manged to implement this solution and can confirm it does work. What am I struggling with though is the why. I don't understand why I need to do the return in the case when the `if` is not true.

I am going to add some of my issues at the bottom of the post can you please help me?

Comment: The  `return` you had in the `if` will indeed return the node to the caller, but because that usually happens deep within the recursion that is going on, it is not the top-level call of `getTargetCopy` that gets that return value, but the "deepest" call within the recursion. That deepest call was made in the part of your function code that is below the `if`, by one of those two calls. But then your code does nothing with that returned value. It ignores it. By consequence the one-but-deepest call of `getTargetCopy` gets nothing back (`None`)... also the original call of `getTargetCopy`.

Comment: To make sure that the value -- that is returned in the "base case" (within the `if`) -- bubbles up right up the recursion stack, you must keep returning it, at every level of recursion.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense to me now!